# Can Android Air have a splash screen using Flash Pro?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, splash-screen

Is there a way to specify a splash screen for an Android AIR application in Flash Pro? I've seen a number of techniques but none for Flash Pro.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Flash Pro is no different than any other AS3 IDE except that it gives you visual tools to create with. You still have access to the exact same code and techniques. You can use `SplashScreenImage` to do it, if you're using Flex. For the most part, you don't want to do anything that runs code on mobile, which is why Flex doesn't allow you to. So no animation, no movement, no anything. Just a static image.

Regardless, any technique you've found should work just fine on Android and with Flash Pro. As I said, there is no difference between an app created with Flash Builder, IntelliJ, Flash Develop, and Flash Pro. They all use the same compiler, same runtime, same codebase, etc.

Comment: Thanks Josh. I don't know where to set SplashScreenImage.

Comment: Are you using Flex? If so, you set it on whatever you top-level class is. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Application.html#splashScreenImage

Comment: Well then use one of the techniques you talked about in your question. As I said, you should not have any issues implementing them, regardless of IDE you are using.

Comment: I don't see any way to implement a splash screen for Android in AS3 using anything I found. This needs to be displayed prior to loading the AIR framework. In Flex there are options to set this which to my understanding sets in at the lower Android level.